# how to find the coefficient of $x^t$ in multiplication of series

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

how to find the coefficient of $x^5$ in $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+.....)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+.....)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+....)(1+x^4+x^8+....)$$
Is there any method in general to find the coefficient of $x^t$ in the above expansion
This question is equivalent to 
 $a+2b+3c+4d=5$
The number of integral solutions for the above equation 
I know how to solve this if the coefficients of the LHS are all one but i do not know how to do it for arbitary coefficients

Comment: I would head for generatingfunctionology. (That's a book:  https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html )

Comment: @aza Welcome to Maths SE.  __2__ things: I have reformatted your post  but the input interpretation may be wrong so in future use
 [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) to learn how to format via $\LaTeX$ and secondly, 
if someone gives an answer that is useful to you don't forget to tick it. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Using a method from *generatingfunctionology*: Note that $1+x^r+x^{2r}+x^{3r} + \cdots = {\displaystyle1\over \displaystyle1-x^r}$. Your product would then be equal to ${\displaystyle1\over \displaystyle(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)} = {\displaystyle1\over \displaystyle(1-x)^4(1+x)^2(1+x+x^2)(1+x^2)} = {{\displaystyle A\over\displaystyle  1-x} + {\displaystyle B\over\displaystyle (1-x)^2} + {\displaystyle C\over \displaystyle (1-x)^3} + {\displaystyle D\over \displaystyle (1-x)^4} + {\displaystyle E\over \displaystyle 1+x} + {\displaystyle F\over \displaystyle (1+x)^2} + {\displaystyle Gx+H \over \displaystyle 1+x+x^2} + {\displaystyle Ix+J \over \displaystyle 1+x^2}}$.

Find the constants, then convert back to a series.

Comment: Don't you think this is really overdoing it for the coefficient of $x^5$? But anyway it's a nice technique for the asker to learn even though I think it's not what he/she was expecting.

Comment: He was also asking for the coefficient of $x^t$, in the main problem. ((EDIT: And he just changed the title.))

Comment: Yup if he's interested in the general case then the technique you give in your answer is indeed the one to use.

Answer (score 0):

Okay lets do this by binomial. In how many ways can you get $5$ as power of $x$ its $5C4=5$ so we just need to add the coefficients got by all the $5$ possibilities .I give you example of $1,1,x^2,x^3$ =  $1.1.1x^2.4x^3$=$4x^5$. 1 for $x^2$ as it can be formed only 1 way. 4 for $x^3$ as it can be formed in $4$ ways. Do it for remaining 4 possibilities add the coefficients and you are done.